# Eliminate all rows until certain value

Tags: sql

I am using an older version of sybase which does not have keywords like lead.

I have a table like one shown below.

```
Type  Row   Time        Quantity        
cat1  1      10:01:01.000     50          
cat1  2      10:01.01.001     0          
cat1  3      10:01:01.002    1000          
cat1  4      10:01.01.003    100          
cat1  5      10:01:03.001    100
```

I have above data available for cat2, cat3, etc. as well. The data is arranged in increasing order of time.

I want to generate a new table from the above table where the values only starting at 10.01.01.002 and later would be present as it is the first row/time where the minimum required quantity of 1000 is satisfied. i.e. include rows 3, 4, and 5 in new table as it is only at 3rd row that minimum quantity is fulfilled. The above data is for cat1, cat2, etc.

The table above is massive so I am looking for an efficient method.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you do `select ... where Time > ....` ?

Comment: @MiserableVariable - because he does not know what the time value should be.

Comment: What's the primary key for the table? Type, row or just row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TOP 1 to find the first item of your criteria then use that in a select statement.

Like this (not sure your exact requirements)

```
declare @marker datetime

SELECT TOP 1 @marker = Time 
FROM TableName 
WHERE Quantity > 1000 ORDER BY Row DESC

SELECT * 
FROM TableName 
WHERE Time > @marker
```

Comment: Thanks! I think your logic serves my purpose.

Comment: @user1949158 - You can select an answer as the one you are using by clicking on the checkmark next to the question.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM tables_name WHERE Row >= 3`
I'm not sure I understood your question correctly. Did you literally want the rows after and including the third or are they just added automatically as part of the formatting? This will only work if Row is primary key.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, can you do something like this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE T 
    JOIN (
        SELECT Type, Row 
        FROM TABLE 
        WHERE Quantity >= 1000
    ) T2 ON T.Type = T2.Type
WHERE T.Row >= T2.Row
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03e3d/2) (granted using SQL Server since I don't see sybase as an option, but I believe sybase supports sub queries)